# Prevent user the label is changing - spriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a label which takes a different value every 5 seconds (string values: "blue", "pink", "green", "orange")

I want to warn the user that the label will change 1 second before.
For example, the background color of label should be red 1 second before the label take another value.

Code which call the color change function every 5 sec

```
let timerFunc: NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: Selector("colorChange"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

code which change the label value randomly

```
 func colorChange() {
    let minRandomValue: UInt = 0
    let maxRandomValue: UInt = 4
    var numberRandom: UInt = UInt()

    numberRandom = UInt(arc4random()) % (maxRandomValue - minRandomValue)

    switch numberRandom {
    case 0: couleur.text = "Blue"; 
    case 1: couleur.text = "Green"; 
    case 2: couleur.text = "Orange"; 
    case 3: couleur.text = "Pink"; 
    default: println("value problem")
    }
}
```

Later I will make the 5 sec Timer delay Random. Thank you. Xcode 6.4, SDK 8.0

Comment: What are you having problems with?

Comment: This code works, I'm asking how to set the label background in red color 1 second before the label change his value. I don't know how to start coding this

Comment: Set another timer with 4.0 seconds delay or if it is randomized, randomValue - 1

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I solved it with Two timers, bother repeated false. Thank for help

Comment: I still recommend using an SKAction approach, because they are coupled to your SKScene. You will have to invalidate the timers when you pause the game and when the game is over.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following...

1) Create an SKNode,
2) Create a red, rectangle SKSpriteNode and add it to the SKNode,
3) Create an SKLabelNode and add it to the SKNode,
4) Run the following action on self

```
let changeColorWaitChangeBackground = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.runBlock(self.changeColor),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(4, withRange:2),
        SKAction.runBlock(self.changeAlpha),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(1),
    ])
```

In changeColor(), set the color string and set the alpha of the red SKSpriteNode to 0.0.

In changeAlpha(), set the alpha of the red SKSpriteNode to 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Change the timer interval to 1.0 so that the `couleurChange` method is called once per second. In the `couleurChange` method keep track of time with a counter.  When the counter reaches 4, change the backgroundColor of the label.  When the counter reaches 5

- change the text of the label
- put the backgroundColor back to its normal value
- set the counter back to 0

Comment: Why call the function 3 times with no actual work done? Two separate timers, one 4 seconds and one 5 seconds is much cleaner...

Comment: No work done means no processor cycles wasted.  With two timers, the timers have to be non-repeating, which means constantly rescheduling them, and that imo is worse than just a few extra calls to the timer callback.

Comment: Thanks you guys, I will try. Btw is there any property to change the background color of an SKLabelNode ? or I need to create another sprite ?

Comment: @user3722523 I think you need to put a SKShapeNode behind the label to give it a background.

Comment: Fair enough @user3386109... I almost always prefer readability before small performance optimizations though. But whatever floats your boat. user3722523, both our solutions will work for you. My solution offers more precise timing, incase you want 1.32 seconds warning.

Comment: Ok, thinking about it, I take it back. I see what you mean about the rescheduling now... A repeating timer of 4 seconds will get out of faze of course... However if you are going to randomize the time rescheduling will be required anyhow.

Comment: @hannesr To randomize the timing, I would generate a random number in the `couleurChange` method and store it as `maxCount`.  When `count == maxCount - 1`, change the background color.  When `count == maxCount`, generate a new `maxCount` in addition to the three bullet items in my answer.  In other words, the timer callback implements a software state machine.